# Why is PrincipalContext ValidateCredentials throwing an exception when given incorrect credentials?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to authenticate the user.  Authentication through PrincipalContext works fine with the correct username and password, but when testing with incorrect credentials, ValidateCredentials throws a System.Exception rather than returning false.  The exception simply states that 'The user name or password is incorrect'.  The stack trace is as follows:

```
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UnsafeNativeMethods.IADs.Get(String bstrName)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.CredentialValidator.BindSam(String target, String userName, String password)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials(String userName, String password)
   at hcv.Core.AuthenticationSystem.Services.WindowsAuthenticationService.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<AuthenticateAsync>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)" string
```

and the code is pretty straight forward:

```
using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(_contextType, _domain))
{
    var isAuthenticated = pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
    return isAuthenticated;
}
```

I am currently working around this by catching the error, checking the message and returning false if it's the incorrect username or password message and rethrowing if not, but that feels hacky.

Does anyone have any idea why the exception is being thrown rather than simply returning false for invalid credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Add `ContextOptions`to the method `ValidateCredentials`.

There is a variety of options depending on the `ContextType`.

Check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300969(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I had looked at the documentation and I have tried various `ContextOptions` settings to no avail.  For every setting I could think to try that made some kind of sense the `ValidateCredentials` call would still throw an exception rather than simply return false, as documented.